# List members visable in any organic group

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups

I am working on a Drupal 7 & OG & Views site, and I am trying to write a view that shows what users another user can 'see' through any group he's a member of.

ie:
User A - Member of Group A, Group AB, Group AC
User B - Member of Group B, Group AB
User C - Member of Group C, Group AC

Output of View for ..
User A - User A, B, C
User B - User A, B
User C - User A, C

Thanks..

Comment: so basically you want to show all the members that belong to the same groups the selected user belongs to?

Comment: Basically, yes..

Answer (score 2):

Go to OG Members > EDIT > CONTEXTUAL FILTERS > PROVIDE DEFAULT VALUES > CURRENT OG GROUP FROM CONTEXT ....i assumed u have the OG MEMBERS which is a default view created after installation of the latest module.